Вытащить определенные кадры из видео
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v libwebp -lavfi "select='eq(n\,1)',scale=-1:'min(720,ih)'" -vsync vfr -start_number 1 img%d.webp

Пытаюсь вытащить 1 кадр, получается, но не понимаю почему запускается процесс.
То есть кадр получила, файл есть, но процесс на этом не останавливается, продолжает обработку видео...
Как выполнить, допустим необходим 1 и 20 кадр. Как обратиться к видео, именно к данным кадрам и на выходе получить 2 файла? И завершить на этом процесс...

Установить какой-нибудь конвертер-редактор видео и не писать велосипеды. Рекомендую Wondershare UniConverter - и нарежет, и разделит, и переконвертирует эффективно, и экран захватит, и веб-камеру.

А если купить, то ещё с десяток супервозможностей...

Не, необходимо именно через ffmpeg

Раз необходимо, так надо работать, не покладая рук. Даже не буду пытаться вникать кому необходимо изобретать велосипеды и зачем.

Я нашёл такое и попробовал, вроде получилось что-то:
Для того, чтобы извлечь определенный кадр из видео с помощью ffmpeg, можно использовать следующую команду:
ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -vf "select=eq(n\,frame_number)" -vsync vfr -q:v 2 output_frame.jpg

Замените input_video.mp4 на имя вашего видеофайла, frame_number на номер кадра, который вы хотите извлечь, и output_frame.jpg на имя выходного файла.
Команда для извлечения несколько кадров по номерам не сработала. Так что, для такого нужно поштучно извлекать кадры в цикле.
